# Python For Loop for Grouped Data with Interrows and Defined Function

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iterator, pandas-groupby

I’m trying to calculate an indicator column, so that it returns a value of 1 IF the given customer returns for another service within 60 days of the given service’s end date. Below is a table of the data and the desired indicator column.

[image]

I’ve sorted and grouped the data by customer and service. Now, I’m trying to put together a formula that looks at the end date of each row and checks if any future service start dates, for that given customer (group), are within a 60 day period.

So far, I've grouped the data and I've tried to apply a for loop... but I keep getting errors. I'm new to Python, so I'm not quite sure how to set up the code and syntax, to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['John','John','Deb','Sara','Sara','Sara','Sara','Sara','Mike','Mike','Mike'],
               'Service':['A','B','C','A','B','C','D','E','E','F','G'],
               'Start':['1/2/2020','3/1/2020','2/5/2020','2/6/2020','3/6/2020','8/2/2020','9/15/2020','10/2/2020','5/4/2020','6/8/2020','7/1/2020'],
               'End':['1/3/2020','3/11/2020','2/7/2020','2/9/2020','3/9/2020','8/12/2020','9/19/2020','10/12/2020','5/8/2020','6/18/2020','7/8/2020']})


df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
df.dtypes

grp=df.groupby(['Customer','Service'])
grp.head(15)

def serv_days(Start,End):
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if (row[1].Start == row.End):
            continue
        if ((row[1].Start-row.End).days < 60):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

for grpnm,each_grp in grp:
    for row in each_grp.iterrows():
        print(serv_days(each_grp,row[1].Start,row.loc('End')))
```

Answer (score 0):

as your mentioned,we can just compare current row to next row, to see whether current row customer equal to next row customer,and current row end date diff next row start date less than 60 days.
follow the mind,we do not need groupby,we need:

- shift the dataframe with `df[1:]` which means delete the first row and keep other rows
- we need to `reset_index` in order to merge by `index` with original  `df`,so now we have a dataframe combine current row and next row in the same row
- just compare `customer` and `customer_next`(the `_next` suffix is add by the `merge` function `suffixes` param) and diff `End` `Start_next`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['John','John','Deb','Sara','Sara','Sara','Sara','Sara','Mike','Mike','Mike'],
               'Service':['A','B','C','A','B','C','D','E','E','F','G'],
               'Start':['1/2/2020','3/1/2020','2/5/2020','2/6/2020','3/6/2020','8/2/2020','9/15/2020','10/2/2020','5/4/2020','6/8/2020','7/1/2020'],
               'End':['1/3/2020','3/11/2020','2/7/2020','2/9/2020','3/9/2020','8/12/2020','9/19/2020','10/12/2020','5/8/2020','6/18/2020','7/8/2020']})

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')

new_df = pd.merge(df,df[1:].reset_index(drop=True),suffixes=['','_next'],left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left')
new_df['indicator'] = (new_df['Customer'] == new_df['Customer_next']) & ((new_df['Start_next']-new_df['End'])<pd.Timedelta('60 days'))
new_df = new_df[['Customer','Service','Start','End','indicator']]
```

```
    Customer    Service   Start         End         indicator
0   John        A         2020-01-02    2020-01-03  TRUE
1   John        B         2020-03-01    2020-03-11  FALSE
2   Deb         C         2020-02-05    2020-02-07  FALSE
3   Sara        A         2020-02-06    2020-02-09  TRUE
4   Sara        B         2020-03-06    2020-03-09  FALSE
5   Sara        C         2020-08-02    2020-08-12  TRUE
6   Sara        D         2020-09-15    2020-09-19  TRUE
7   Sara        E         2020-10-02    2020-10-12  FALSE
8   Mike        E         2020-05-04    2020-05-08  TRUE
9   Mike        F         2020-06-08    2020-06-18  TRUE
10  Mike        G         2020-07-01    2020-07-08  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections @nay, I fixed the end dates and added a sample table of the results that I was hoping to get. The code you provided is a big help, but returns all 1's... I think it only compares the start/end dates of the current row?
When we look at customer Sara, for example, I was hoping to compare the end date for service A to all future service start dates - to check if any are within 60 days. Then same for the next row. I need to compare Sara's end date for service B to all future start dates, to see if she had further services done within 60 days, etc.